# what is f option means when using with fgrep

Tags: grep

I came across this line of coding of previous developer's script and do not understand.

Could anyone please tell me what it means?

```
fgrep -f ${OLD_LOG} ${NEW_LOG} > ${SAME_FILE} 2>&1
```

Comment: Check the man page :
-f FILE, --file=FILE
              Obtain patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty  file
              contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  Multiple
              -f can be used to specify different files.

Answer (score 0):

Usually linux programs/commands have a man page that explains everything. Access it next time by

`man fgrep` or `man <command>`